# Cannot use environment variable in CMakePresets.json with CMakeTools in VSCode to set CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE

Tags: cmake, vscode-extensions, vcpkg

I have run into an issue regarding using environment variables in CMakePresets.json to set the `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` to the vcpkg folder. I have set an environment system variable `VCPKG_ROOT` to `D:/Apps/vcpkg/vcpkg`.

My CMakePresets.json looks like this:

```
{
"version": 3,
"configurePresets": [
    {
        "name": "default",
        "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/build",
        "cacheVariables": {
            "CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE": "$env{VCPKG_ROOT}/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"
        }
    }
]
}
```

When I try to build the project with CMakeTools, I get the following error message: `[cmake]   Could not find toolchain file: /scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake`

If I use the full path, `D:/Apps/vcpkg/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake`, the build succeeds.

Does anyone have an idea why the environment variable is treated as empty? I also tried using `$env:VCPKG_ROOT`, `$VCPKG_ROOT`, `${VCPKG_ROOT}` to no success.

I got the CMakePresets.json file from the [Microsoft vcpkg and VS Code guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcpkg/get_started/get-started-vscode?pivots=shell-cmd#:%7E:text=To%20allow%20the%20CMake%20project%20system%20to%20recognize%20C%2B%2B%20libraries%20provided%20by%20vcpkg%2C%20you%27ll%20need%20to%20provide%20the%20vcpkg.cmake%20toolchain%20file.%20To%20automate%20this%2C%20create%20a%20CMakePresets.json%20file%20in%20the%20%22helloworld%22%20directory%20with%20the%20following%20content%3A)

It is not a huge problem but I would still like to know the cause of the issue. Thank you in advance!

Comment: How exactly have you set `VCPKG_ROOT` variable? Have you followed the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcpkg/get_started/get-started-vscode?pivots=shell-cmd#3---setup-vcpkg) you have referenced?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I have the exact same problem and it's driving me crazy!